# Bijection Between Maps of Covering Spaces and Maps of Fundamental Groupoid Covers

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups, groupoids

I'm reading May's *Concise Course in Algebraic Topology.* He states:

[image]

My question is about this last corollary.
How does the bijection $\text{Cov}(E, E') \to \text{Cov}(\Pi(E), \Pi(E'))$ immediately follow from the Theorem?

Comment: What exactly did he state? (As of now it looks as if he was stating a question)

Comment: @ArcticChar oops! The statement that I am interested in is "COROLLARY: The fundamental groupoid functor induces a bijection...". The last sentence/question in my post was written by me; I'm realizing now that the font on Math.se looks almost the exact same as the typeface used in May's book.